# How to increase a date field with one second value in a MongoDB 3.6?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.6

MongoDB scripting is still pretty cryptic to me, and stuck with this problem on a 3.6 server lacking the fancier operators from 4.2.

How to increase a date field with one second value in a MongoDB 3.6?

For example, I'd like to do something like this:

```
db.getCollection("therecords").update(
   { 
      "_id" : ObjectId("123etc")
   }, 
   { 
      $set: {
         updatedAt : "$updatedAt" + 1 ;
      }
   }
);
```

…will set the value to the text `$updatedAt1` which is cute.

Other cute errors are thrown when using `updatedAt` without quotes or without the $ prefix.

More generically, is there a way to reuse current values with `update … $set`?

Comment: i don't think it is possible to do in single query in mongodb 3.6, you have to do 2 queries, first find and second update/save.

Comment: I'd be happy to do it with multiple queries, in an aggregation or with some MongoDB Shell magic. I'd just prefer to stay in the MongoDB environment (i.e. via Studio 3T) and not install another tool or environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to do this using single query in MongoDB v3.6, but:

1. `find()` specific documents
2. `forEach()` found document, get the date and bump
3. `save()` it back

```
db.getCollection("therecords").find(
    { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("123etc") 
    }
).forEach(function(doc) {
   var d = new Date(doc.createdAt);
   d.setSeconds(d.getSeconds() + 1);
   doc.createdAt = d;
   db.getCollection("therecords").save(doc); // Save each back
});
```